# Plot is not generating the heat map for tune model (SVM)

Tags: r

I'm using R-Studio and e1071 package for SVM (Support Vector Machine). Iris dataset is the typical one used in R.

The code is the following:

```
tune_model <-tune(svm, Species~., data=iris,
             ranges= list(epsilon= seq(0, 1, 0.1)), #epsilon= 0, 0.1, 0.2 etc
             cost=2^(2:9)) #default cost=1
                           #if cost is too high--> high penalty for non-separable points--> will use too many support vectors-->overfitting
                           #if cost is too low--> underfitting
plot(tune_model)
```

However I'm getting:

[image: Tuning output]

Whereas I should be getting a heatmap:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `cost = 2^(2:9)` be *inside* your `ranges = list(...)` parameters, rather than come after it?

Comment: Yes! That solved it,  thanks!